# How to list sources in makefile?

Tags: makefile

What is the tidiest way to list a series of source files which will eventually be comma delimited?

My knowledge of makefiles is poor, so I have written what I am after using pseudo-code:

```
sources = array(
    'my/file1',
    'my/file2',
    //...
    'my/file30'
)

executable -source=${implode(',', sources)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with thanks to: [Create comma-separated lists in GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525589/create-comma-seperated-lists-in-gnu-make)

```
sources = my/file1 \
my/file2 \
my/file3

null  :=
space := $(null) #
comma := ,

FULL_SOURCES := $(subst $(space),$(comma),$(strip $(sources)))
```